# What is the max possible length of a PID of a process? (64 bit)

Tags: c

I have been working on AIX and see some of the process ID's running are 8 long....

I am using the PID as a concatenation with another char* value and am trying to work out what that MAX possible length of a PID if you were looking at it from a "char perspective"?

I have looked at the pid_t structure (for example t.html">http://dvbstreamer.sourceforge.net/api/structPID_t.html) and it has the PID as an INT...

On that note I assume a PID is a "signed int"....in that case what is a signed int's max length?

Thanks for the help

Lynton

Comment: *"8 long"* -- 8 *what* long?  Are you talking about the length of a string representing the PID value in decimal (e.g., 8374 is 4 digits long)?  And don't assume that a PID is a signed int; it's a `pid_t`, which may or may not be a typedef for `signed int`.

Comment: Hi there, yup...I meant the string representation of the PID...thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size in bytes is system dependent and should simply be queried like this:

```
unsigned int pidLength = sizeof(pid_t);
```

**Edit**: If you're worried about the length *decimal representation* as in `printf("%d", myPID);`, I suggest querying that, too. For example, the `snprintf` function returns the number of characters (without null-termination) it would have written if there were enough space. So you can do:

```
char tmpChar;
int representationLength = snprintf(&tmpChar, 1, "%d", myPID);
if (representationLength == -1) { handle_error(); }
char *finalString = malloc(representationLength + 1);
snprintf(finalString, representationLength + 1, "%d", myPID);
```

Maybe `snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", myPID)` would work to query the length as well, but the Linux `snprintf` man page says this:

> Concerning the return value of snprintf(), SUSv2 and C99 contradict each other: when snprintf() is called with size=0 then SUSv2 stipulates an unspecified return value less than 1, while C99 allows str to be NULL in this case, and gives the return value (as always) as the number of characters that would have been written in case the output string has been large enough.

Comment: "the PID as a concatenation with another char* value"... he wants the max length if he converts the PID to a string.

Comment: Yup, after reading your answer I was a bit confused and re-read the question. Have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of digits in an 32-bit int is 10.

The maximum number of digits in a 64-bit signed int is 19.

The maximum number of digits in a 64-bit unsigned int is 20.

I don't know if AIX uses 32 or 64 bits, signed or unsigned, for its `pid_t`.

Edit: it's gotta be signed because fork can return -1.

Comment: We also could define ~((pid_t) 0) as an invalid PID and use an unsigned 64bit type as pid_t ... - I mean just in case we need so many processes on our OS ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to use (int)log10(pid) + 1.  Of course, you might need to include space for a terminating null character, but the above should give you the number of characters needed to represent the value as a string.